# setup-Simple-Cabal fails to install while building haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Stack tried to install (`stack install` in directory of the downloaded `ghc-mod`-repo) haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1, but as it reached setup-Simple-Cabal, the following error occurred:

```
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Logs have been written to: /home/julius/HaskApps/ghc-mod/.stack-work/logs/haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1.log

Configuring haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1...
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.18.1.5-x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4: The program happy version
>=1.17 is required but it could not be found.
```

setup-Simple-Cabal was part of the `ghc-mod`-installation with stack support ([link to github](https://github.com/parsonsmatt/ghc-mod/tree/stack-support)). Because some errors were thrown regarding the `mtl`-package:

```
Failure when adding dependencies:    
  mtl: needed (>=2.2 && <2.3), 2.1.3.1 found (latest is 2.2.1)
needed for package: MonadRandom-0.3.0.2

Failure when adding dependencies:    
  MonadRandom: needed (>=0.1 && <0.5), couldn't resolve its dependencies
needed for package: either-4.3.4.1

Failure when adding dependencies:    
  monad-journal: needed (>=0.4), couldn't resolve its dependencies
needed for package: ghc-mod-0

Failure when adding dependencies:    
  either: needed (>=4.1 && <4.5), couldn't resolve its dependencies
needed for package: monad-journal-0.7.1
```

I executed `stack solver --modify-stack-yaml --resolver=ghc-7.8` and it solved (haha) the problem at first. However, something seems to require `haskell-src-exts >=1.17`, obviously. This version doesn't even seem to exist. Running `ag "haskell-src-exts >=1.17"` returns no results. What could fix this problem?

EDIT: *Sooo*... Everything seems really strange. I used `stack install` to install everything. It didn't complain about anything until this `haskell-srcexts`/`happy` problem. **However**, when I try `stack solver`, the following error message appears:

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: ghc-mod (user goal)
rejecting: ghc-mod-5.4.0.0, 5.3.0.0, 5.2.1.2, 5.2.1.1, 5.2.1.0, 5.2.0.0,
5.1.1.0, 5.1.0.2, 5.1.0.1, 5.1.0.0, 5.0.1.2, 5.0.1.1, 5.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.1.6,
4.1.5, 4.1.4, 4.1.3, 4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.2, 4.0.1, 4.0.0, 3.1.7, 3.1.6,
3.1.5, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.2, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.1.2, 2.1.1,
2.1.0, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.12.5, 1.12.4, 1.12.3, 1.12.2, 1.12.1,
1.12.0, 1.11.5, 1.11.4, 1.11.3, 1.11.2, 1.11.1, 1.11.0, 1.10.18, 1.10.17,
1.10.16, 1.10.15, 1.10.14, 1.10.13, 1.10.12, 1.10.11, 1.10.10, 1.10.9, 1.10.8,
1.10.7, 1.10.6, 1.10.5, 1.10.4, 1.10.3, 1.10.2, 1.10.1, 1.10.0, 1.0.8, 1.0.7,
1.0.6, 1.0.5, 1.0.4, 1.0.3, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.5,
0.5.4, 0.5.3, 0.5.2, 0.5.1, 0.4.4, 0.4.3, 0.4.2, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.0, 0.2.0,
0.1.0 (global constraint requires ==0)
rejecting: ghc-mod-0 (global constraint requires ==5.2.1.2)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

What is this 'global constraint'? I would suspect a malformed `extra-deps` section in `stack.yaml`, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

EDIT2: stack.yaml:

```
flags:
  text:
    integer-simple: false
  QuickCheck:
    base4point8: false
  transformers-compat:
    three: true
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps:
- HUnit-1.3.0.0
- MonadRandom-0.1.13
- QuickCheck-2.8.1
- StateVar-1.1.0.1
- ansi-terminal-0.6.2.3
- async-2.0.2
- base-orphans-0.4.4
- bifunctors-5
- cabal-helper-0.3.5.0
- cereal-0.4.1.1
- cmdargs-0.10.13
- comonad-4.2.7.2
- contravariant-1.3.3
- cpphs-1.19.3
- data-default-0.5.3
- data-default-class-0.0.1
- data-default-instances-base-0.0.1
- data-default-instances-containers-0.0.1
- data-default-instances-dlist-0.0.1
- data-default-instances-old-locale-0.0.1
- distributive-0.4.4
- djinn-ghc-0.0.2.3
- djinn-lib-0.0.1.2
- dlist-0.7.1.2
- doctest-0.10.1
- either-4.4.1
- exceptions-0.8.0.2
- extra-1.4.2
- free-4.12.1
- ghc-paths-0.1.0.9
- ghc-syb-utils-0.2.3
- hashable-1.2.3.3
- haskell-src-exts-1.16.0.1
- hlint-1.9.21
- hscolour-1.23
- hspec-2.2.0
- hspec-core-2.2.0
- hspec-discover-2.2.0
- hspec-expectations-0.7.2
- mmorph-1.0.4
- monad-control-1.0.0.4
- monad-journal-0.7.1
- mtl-2.1.3.1
- nats-1
- polyparse-1.11
- prelude-extras-0.4.0.2
- primitive-0.6.1.0
- profunctors-5.1.1
- quickcheck-io-0.1.2
- random-1.1
- semigroupoids-5.0.0.4
- semigroups-0.17.0.1
- setenv-0.1.1.3
- split-0.2.2
- stm-2.4.4
- syb-0.6
- tagged-0.8.1
- temporary-1.2.0.3
- text-1.2.1.3
- tf-random-0.5
- transformers-base-0.4.4
- transformers-compat-0.4.0.4
- uniplate-1.6.12
- unordered-containers-0.2.5.1
- void-0.7.1
resolver: lts-2.16
```

Comment: That's strange. Stackage has `haskell-src-exts`, so it should install fine. What command did you use to install ? Also note that error message says that the package [happy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/happy) >= 1.17 is not being able to find, not of `haskell-src-exts`.

Comment: do you have happy installed? (or tried to install it?)

Comment: I don't have happy installed (as far as I know; `ag -g happy` and `which happy` don't show any results). I didn't try to install it either.

Comment: Can you post your stack.yaml file ?

Comment: Note that according to Stack documentation, you should list package on `extra-deps` section only when the package is not on the LTS. But I think that is not the case with you ? How did you generate the yaml file ?

Comment: anyway: install happy (don't know it this works with stack - but if you want you can put it in a sandbox `cabal sandbox init` + `cabal install happy` and copy the executable somewhere where in your PATH

Comment: @Carsten I'm not sure, but I think stack automatically takes care of thing like happy, alex etc.

Comment: maybe not - but just try to install it - this happens to me with *vanilla* cabal all the time

Comment: Thank you! I installed happy and everything works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was `happy`, not `haskell-src-exts`. I misinterpreted the error message. So I just installed the `happy` package (via APT), and everything worked out fine.